# How to Connect Windows Phone 8 emulator to internet through 3g usb modem?

Tags: visual-studio, networking, emulation, windows-phone, hyper-v

I am trying to connect Windows phone 8 emulator to internet.

Android emulator and Windows Phone 7 emulator connect to Internet by sharing host Internet connection, but Windows Phone 8 emulator introduced a new model for networking. It uses Hyper-V which creates a virtual switch for each possible Internet connection. The host of the emulator is  Windows 8, as it is required To use Windows phone 8 emulator or Hyper-V .

Now if I use Wi-Fi internet connection at the host ,I connect normally to internet inside the windows phone emulator. but if I connect the host to Internet  through 3G USB modem , I get :

```
We are having trouble displaying this page.
```

Before trying, I uninstalled VirtualBox and Intel Hardware Acceleration Execution Manager (HAXM), so this rules them out of the problem.

How do i connect using the 3G modem? what settings should i do in Hyper-V manager or the network connection to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a loopback adapter and then using that to connect to the internet?

[How to install a loopback adapter](http://ceekam.com/blog/?p=1057)

[Using a loopback adapter](http://beamex.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/using-microsft-loopback-adapter-to-get-online-with-your-3g-modem-or-mobile-phone/)

I use Tata Photon+ 3G modem ... unfortunately I have not been able to get it working yet.

However, I have already messed up lot of network settings and thinking of doing it all over from scratch.

if you find any luck do post back the steps.

Comment: Sorry. I tried it but it didn't work. Microosoft requires DHCP and this configuration doesn't have it . I had to use a 3g wifi router.